# Perl Hash references to the hash values inside same hash

Tags: perl, perl-hash

My requirement is as below. Inside the same hash the values of keys are dependent on other key value as shown below

```
my %test;

$test{map}{a} = 32;
$test{map}{b} = $test{map}{a}+10;
$test{ref}{r} = $test{map}{b};
```

So, when I do 
    print Dumper(\%test);
I get

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ref' => {
                     'r' => 42
                   },
          'map' => {
                     'a' => 32,
                     'b' => 42
                   }
        };
```

If I change the hash value

```
$test{map}{a} = 42
```

I get

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ref' => {
                     'r' => 42
                   },
          'map' => {
                     'a' => 42,
                     'b' => 42
                   }
        };
```

Instead, I should have the updated hash %test as shown below

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ref' => {
                     'r' => 52
                   },
          'map' => {
                     'a' => 42,
                     'b' => 52
                   }
        };
```

How to achieve the above result? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Thank you larsen & Apoorv Joshi. The resolution that you provided helped me to implement the code the way I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics of the code you wrote is not what you imagined. In particular:

```
$test{map}{b} = $test{map}{a}+10;
$test{ref}{r} = $test{map}{b};
```

These **are not** -as I think you imagined- "rules" to obtain the value of `$test{map}{b}` and `$test{map}{b}` every time someone reads them, but instructions that when executed modify the value associated with the keys `b` and `r`. And that's it.

If you want the elements in your hash to be dynamic, one possible approach could be to use references to subroutines, plus a mechanism to evaluate these rules when the user asks for the values. But be advised that could get complicated: for example, what about circular references? Or rules that reference other rules, as the key `r` in your example?

Anyway, here some code as a proof of concept:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my %test;

$test{map}{a} = 32;
$test{map}{b} = sub { evaluate( $test{map}{a} ) + 10 };
$test{ref}{r} = sub { evaluate( $test{map}{b} ) };

sub evaluate {
  my $expr = shift;
  if ( ref $expr eq 'CODE' ) {
    # We need to execute the procedure indicated 
    # to obtain a value
    return $expr->();
  }
  else {
    # Otherwise, we just return what we found associated to the key
    return $expr;
  }
}

say evaluate( $test{ map }{ a } ); # 32
say evaluate( $test{ map }{ b } ); # 42
say evaluate( $test{ ref }{ r } ); # 42

$test{map}{a} = 42;

say evaluate( $test{ map }{ a } ); # 42
say evaluate( $test{ map }{ b } ); # 52
say evaluate( $test{ ref }{ r } ); # 52
```

Again, developing a general and solid solution is by no means a trivial project. If you're interested in these techniques from a Perl point of view a very good book is [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/), also available online for free.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is instead of assigning the value, assign a subroutine. For eg:

```
my %test;

$test{map}{a} = 32;
$test{map}{b} = sub { return $test{map}{a}+10; };
$test{ref}{r} = sub { return $test{map}{b}(); };

print $test{ref}{r}() . "\n";

$test{map}{a} = 42;

print $test{ref}{r}() . "\n";
```